# Sorting an nsmutable array --> order is not being saved?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

kind of a noob question maybe: I'm trying to sort an nsmutablearray, but somehow the order is not being stored.

```
    typedef struct {
        float distance;
        int index;
    } DistanceAndIndex;
    i = 0;   
    NSMutableArray *orderedDistances = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:(self.wayPoints.count)];
CLLocation* rwp2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:52.080752 longitude:4.7527251];
        latLonToEcef(rwp2.coordinate.latitude, rwp2.coordinate.longitude, 0.0, &myX, &myY, &myZ);

        for (routeWayPoint *rwp in [[self wayPoints] objectEnumerator]) {
            double poiX, poiY, poiZ, e, n, u;


            latLonToEcef(rwp.location.coordinate.latitude, rwp.location.coordinate.longitude, 0.0, &poiX, &poiY, &poiZ);
            ecefToEnu(rwp2.coordinate.latitude, rwp2.coordinate.longitude, myX, myY, myZ, poiX, poiY, poiZ, &e, &n, &u);

            DistanceAndIndex distanceAndIndex;
            distanceAndIndex.distance = sqrtf(n*n + e*e);
            distanceAndIndex.index = i;

            NSLog(@"Index = %i, %f", i, distanceAndIndex.distance);
            [orderedDistances insertObject:[NSData dataWithBytes:&distanceAndIndex length:sizeof(distanceAndIndex)] atIndex:i++];
        }
        i=0;


        [orderedDistances sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(NSData *a, NSData *b) {
            const DistanceAndIndex *aData = (const DistanceAndIndex *)a.bytes;
            const DistanceAndIndex *bData = (const DistanceAndIndex *)b.bytes;


            if (aData->distance < bData->distance) {
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            } else if (aData->distance > bData->distance) {
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            } else {
                return NSOrderedSame;
            }
        }];


        for (NSData *d in [orderedDistances reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
            const DistanceAndIndex *distanceAndIndex = (const DistanceAndIndex *)d.bytes;        
            NSLog(@"item: %i, %f", distanceAndIndex->index, distanceAndIndex->distance);
        }
```

The output is the following:

[2021:907] Waypoints: 8
[2021:907] Index = 0, 230.078827

[2021:907] Index = 1, 171.626389

[2021:907] Index = 2, 36.015743

[2021:907] Index = 3, 103.174805

[2021:907] Index = 4, 238.837616

[2021:907] Index = 5, 278.074371

[2021:907] Index = 6, 288.319763

[2021:907] Index = 7, 321.953156

[2021:907] item: 7, 321.953156

[2021:907] item: 6, 288.319763

[2021:907] item: 5, 278.074371

[2021:907] item: 4, 238.837616

[2021:907] item: 3, 103.174805

[2021:907] item: 2, 36.015743

[2021:907] item: 1, 171.626389

[2021:907] item: 0, 230.078827

The array simply hasn't been reordered (for instance when looking at items 1,2 and 3). I feel like I'm overlooking something really basic. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Quick observation, you have two if statements that both return NSOrderedAscending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be overlooking this typo:

```
       if (aData->distance < bData->distance) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        } else if (aData->distance > bData->distance) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        } else {
            return NSOrderedSame;
        }
```

The second one should be `NSOrderedDescending`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two if statements that both return NSOrderedAscending